# CS5: How to make non-linear changes using the history panel?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, history

I made a mistake in the below image by making the left-pointing arrow too high up, such that the black margins do not align.

I wish to go back and change this "combining paths" action, without undoing any of the changes I made subsequently. It appears there is a "Allow non-linear history" option in the History Panel options. However, I'm not sure if this works retroactively... Furthermore, will switching to this not make life difficult when I DON'T wish to make non-linear edits, but eliminate all changes after the one I am editing?

[image]

Comment: If they are paths, can't you simply use the Direct Selection Tool to reposition the arrow?

Comment: Late response, but the problem was that I already combined the paths, so the arrow is no longer an arrow on its own. That's what I wish to go back and change, but made many actions after this one...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing any of these things?

**Restore part of an image to its previously saved version**

Do one of the following:

- Use the History Brush tool  to paint with the selected state or
  snapshot on the History panel.
- Use the Eraser tool  with the Erase To History option selected.
- Select the area you want to restore, and choose Edit > Fill. For Use,
  choose History, and click OK.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try these out and I'll come back here to report. Not sure I understood the last suggestion entirely? Which area exactly am I selecting, and what did the last sentence mean? Thank you for this.